# Checking For Existence of Getters in Java Without Triggering Exception

Tags: java, reflection

Trying to use reflection to see if a class has a getter defined for each of its fields:

```
Arrays.stream(entityClass.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(field -> {
    try {           
        PropertyDescriptor pd = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(entityClass, field.getName());

        if(null == PropertyUtils.getReadMethod(pd)) {
            // no getter found, this is what I need to act on
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // 
    }
});
```

Problem is, `BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor` throws an exception if a field does not have both a getter and a setter defined and that breaks the logic flow of this piece of code.  I understand that this is because it expects the class to adhere to the Java bean spec which requires getters/setters... however in this case the classes don't necessarily do so (they're not strictly Java beans).  So I suppose this approach won't work.  Are there alternatives?  3rd party e.g. Apache commons would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If would use Java's build in Reflection functionality for this:

```
public Optional<Method> findGetter(Field field) {

  Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
  String methodPrefix;
  if (fieldType == boolean.class) {
    methodPrefix = "is";
  } else {
    methodPrefix = "get";
  }

  String methodName = methodPrefix + field.getName();
  Class<?> declaringClass = field.getDeclaringClass();

  for (Method method : declaringClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    
    String name = method.getName();
    int modifiers = declaringClass.getModifiers();
    if (Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) || !Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) || method.getParameterCount() != 0) {
      continue;
    }
    if (fieldType.equals(method.getReturnType()) && methodName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
      return Optional.of(method);
    }
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

This code ignores capitalization rules for getter methods. So if you want to be closer to the JavaBeans spec you would need to extend this. If you should plan to do more reflection stuff I recommend to have a closer look on the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library. Just for this simple task I wouldn't introduce a complete library + this way you can define precisely what you allow as getter method and what not.